# Strange result using ColdFusion custom tag

Tags: coldfusion

I created a simple custom tag which takes a string, replaces whitespace with "-" and "&" with "and" for a querystring (I don't want %20's and the like).

Anyways, it works fine, however my custom tag is creating a space before itself like so:

qsEncode.cfm: (custom tag)

```
<cfparam name="attributes.string" type="string" default="">

<cfset whitespace = Replace(attributes.string," ","-","all")>
<cfset ampersand =  Replace(whitespace,"&","and","all")>

<cfoutput>#ampersand#</cfoutput>
```

The implementation of the tag:

```
<a href="?Page=<cf_qsEncode string="#getCategory.Name#">">#getCategory.Name#</a>
```

And the final output which is creating a space before the tag:

```
somepage.cfm?Page=%20Finance-and-Taxes
```

My custom tag isn't being passed a string that has whitespace prepended to it (and even if it was it would be replaced by the "-" character) so I don't understand why the tag is creating whitespace.

**Note:** I do realize I can include `?Page=` inside my custom tag which would fix it, but I'm still curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Is the "%20" part of the input string? If it is, and you're expecting it to be replaced by the replace() for " ", then you're mistaken; "%20" is still the string "%20" unless you `urlDecode()` it (or if it's actually in a query parameter, then it will be automatically decoded before being exposed in the URL scope).

Comment: @Adam, No, %20 wasn't part of the input string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your specific problem with extra space can likely be fixed by using:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
```

as the very first thing inside your custom tag (and setting it back to "false" at the end).

However, I would highly recommend replacing the functionality of the custom tag with an actual function -- either inline, or (preferably) within a cfc. Either way, you want something like this:

```
<cffunction name="qsEncode" output="false" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="str" type="string" required="true">
  <cfset var whitespace = Replace(arguments.str," ","-","all")>
  <cfset var ampersand = Replace(whitespace,"&","and","all")> 
  <cfreturn ampersand>
</cffunction>
```

Then you'd have:

```
<a href="?Page=#qsEncode(getCategory.Name)#">#getCategory.Name#</a>
```

For utility functions like these that don't maintain state, a quick solution (putting aside arguments as to the wisdom of singletons) is to set up a utility cfc, and store it as a singleton in the application scope. Instantiate the `utility.cfc` in the `onApplicationStart` handler of your `Application.cfc`. Then, throughout your application, you can do things like this:

```
application.utility.qsEncode('this');
application.utility.someOtherFunction('that');
application.utility.yetAnotherStringMangler('theother');
```

Comment: @Ken, can you tell me how to instantiate the function in `Application.cfc`?

Comment: @Nick, in `Application.cfc` you should have an `onApplicationStart` function. It will run when you start your app (or manually trigger the function). In there, you'd have something like `application.utility = createobject('component','utility')`. If you want detailed help, check out the CF documentation, other SO answers -- or perhaps ask another question here.

Comment: @Ken, the existing project I have been assigned to had an `application.cfm` not.cfc. However I tried `<cfset application.utility = createobject('component','utility')` and then your previous syntax and got it working.

Comment: @Nick, if you must work with `Application.cfm`, make sure you check for the existence of `application.utility`, only creating it if it does not already exist. You only want to instantiate it once -- when the app starts up (or you reset it). You should also read up [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appFramework_16.html) on the use of `Application.cfm` and `<cflock>`, which you'll want to use to prevent race conditions or potentially ambiguous variable access.

Answer (score 0):

Ken is correct - the white space in your custom tag CFM is creating the extra space in it's output. And I recommend his answer (I prefer calling UDF functions in over custom tag CFMs... even better as a function in a CFC object over CFM).

But if you want to simply adjust your existing custom tag, use CFSILENT to stifle whitespace output (and assure no trailing whitespace after last tag in the file).

```
<cfsilent>
<cfparam name="attributes.string" type="string" default="">

<cfset whitespace = Replace(attributes.string," ","-","all")>
<cfset ampersand =  Replace(whitespace,"&","and","all")>

</cfsilent><cfoutput>#ampersand#</cfoutput>
```